# Guitar pickup / PhotoMOS off-state leak

Tags: solid-state-relay

Brand new member here.

I'm using an AQY211EH PhotoMOS relay to switch guitar pickups via an Arduino, as shown below:

[image: Use of AQY211EH in guitar mod project]

This works great, with one minor exception: even when no power is applied to the Arduino (and, thus, the circuit as a whole), I still get a signal from the pickups to the amplifier. According to the [datasheet](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/500000-524999/504846-da-01-en-PHOTOMOS_RELAIS_AQY_1A_400MA_60V.pdf), the maximum leak current should be 1 micro-amp.

So, two questions, really. One is should less than 1uA should be detectable by my guitar amplifier?

The second, are there ways to eliminate (or reduce) this leakage through additional circuitry on the Guitar-Amp pathway?

My biggest worry here is that the off-state leakage is also present when the other pickup has power, leading to a change in the overall tone from a normally switched guitar (where there is NO off-state leakage).

Thanks. Happy to clarify further if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1uA is the *maximum* leakage over temperature and voltage. At zero volts the typical leakage is 10<sup>-13</sup>A (less than a picoamp). However the capacitance at zero volts is about 250pF, which may be significant.

[image]

Most guitar preamps have a very high input impedance, typically ranging from 1 to 10 MegOhms. The PhotoMOS capacitance and preamp input resistance form a high pass RC filter with cutoff frequency of $$fc=\frac{1}{2\pi R C}$$ For 250pF and 1M that works out to 636Hz. However the pickup inductance and cable capacitance also have an effect. A typical 15ft cable has a capacitance of ~450pF, so the complete equivalent circuit might look something like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG0phd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Cable capacitance causes some attenuation in the pass band, but the cutoff frequency is also greatly reduced. The result is you will still hear a fairly strong signal even when the PhotoMOS relay is turned off.

To combat this you need to swap the PhotoMOS relay for one with much lower capacitance. Since the pickup impedance is very high you don't need a high current relay, so choose one with higher resistance and lower capacitance.

Comment: I learned an important lesson today. In my haste to get something that would handle AC with a 3.3V circuit for the switch control, I totally ignored capacitance. Rookie mistake, but probably a lesson I'll never forget… Thanks for taking the time to make that so clear.

Comment: Incidentally - a micro amp into 1 M would give 1V...

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to fix this.

1) If you don't care what happens to the signal from the guitar when the signal is turned supposed to be turned OFF, simply arrange your photo-MOS relay so that it shorts out the guitar signal when the relay is turned ON.  This has the added advantage of (mostly) dropping out of circuit if your Arduino loses power.

2) If you need the guitar signal to not he damaged when the switch is not passing audio, keep your photo-MOS relay in series with the signal as you have shown *but* also add another photo-MOS relay in parallel with the amplifier input to ground.  This relay is turned ON when the first relay is OFF and vice-versa.

This disconnects the guitar signal from the amplifier *and* shunts the amplifier input to ground when the signal path is turned OFF.

Note that neither of these solutions offers much relief from the capacitance of your chosen photo-MOS relay.  If this turns out to be a problem, your only option will be to either choose a different device or move to either a different circuit topology *or* move to a mechanical relay.

If you want to look at a different circuit topology, have a look at some of the circuits on the web that use one or more J-FETs for switching audio.  Some J-FETs have *very* low capacitance between S & D and your guitar signal is a sufficiently-low voltage that you shouldn't have much problem switching it.  Again, many circuits use both series and shunt switch elements go get high isolation when the audio path is supposed to be OFF.

One of the audio switches that I used many years ago in some of my wired headset audio intercom systems uses a pair of J175 P-channel JFETs as a cascaded shunt switch.  Series R from the mic preamp, shunt J175 to ground, another series R from the 1st J175 to the next shunt J175 and then on to the hybrid input.  So the hybrid input saw the audio from the mic preamp via those two series resistors when the J176s were high-resistance.  But when the J175s were set to low resistance, the hybrid saw the mic preamp audio through a pair of cascaded voltage dividers (the series R plus the shunt RET's channel resistance).  This gave attenuation near 80dB, which was way more than enough.

The only limitation in that circuit is that the audio level from the mic preamp could not ever exceed a peak value of a diode drop or the JFETs would create distortion.  I simply ensured that the level from the mic preamp never exceeded 1V p-p even under extremely-loud levels into the microphone.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I am buckling down to educate myself on J-FET audio switches now. Thanks for lighting the way!

Answer (score 0):

A *normal* signal from an electric guitar won't be much bigger than a microamp, so the level of leakage you describe would indeed be very noticeable.  Adding a resistor in parallel with the amplifier's input would reduce the level of stray audio, but would also reduce the pickup sensitivity; it may also affect the behavior of the guitar's tone controls (for better or for worse).  I suspect a 100K resistor would affect behavior noticeably but perhaps not horribly.  Unfortunately, I suspect it would probably reduce leakage audio noticeably but not really eliminate it.  Still, it might be worth trying as a starting point.